# Gitlab CI conditional statement does not work as expected: Both AND and OR conditions

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to have the following condition for a job in Gitlab CI (Gitlab cloud).

- The destination branch should be either `master` or `production`
- The commit should have a tag associated with it with the pattern of `vx.x.x` or `vx.x`

First, I thought the following statement should work:

```
only:
      - master
      - production
only:
      - tags
only:
      - /^v[0-9](?:\.[0-9]){2,3}/
```

But it turns out no matter how you arrange `only` it always considers the different statements as `OR`. So I came with the following statement to see if I can address it properly:

```
only:
      - tags
      - /^v[0-9](?:\.[0-9]){2,3}/
except:
      - /^(?!master)/
      - /^(?!production)/
```

That didn't work either. Then I thought I should be able to use `rules` which is very recently added to Gitlab CI:

```
rules:  
      - if: '($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH == "production") && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v[0-9](?:\.[0-9]){2,3}/'
        when: always
```

However, turns out the syntax is incorrect and using parentheses is not allowed. Then I came to the following statement:

```
rules: 
      - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH == "master" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v[0-9](?:\.[0-9]){2,3}/'
        when: always
      - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH == "production" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v[0-9](?:\.[0-9]){2,3}/'
        when: always
```

But the above statement did not work either. I would appreciate if someone can help me to understand how the requested conditions can be met in Gitlab CI.

Comment: Due to a bug (or expected behaviour not sure) `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is always empty when used with `$CI_COMMIT_TAG`. See: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/26548 So if you are using rules you can only use `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` alone.

Answer (score 2):

I performed some tests on gilab.com project with version GitLab Enterprise Edition 12.3.0-pre.
[Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced) says:

> With only, individual keys are logically joined by an AND:
>
> (any of refs) AND (any of variables) AND (any of changes) AND (if
> kubernetes is active)

So I created pipeline as follows to test it:

```yaml
build0-refs:
  script:
    - env | sort
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - production
build1-variables:
  script:
    - env | sort
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v[0-9](?:\.[0-9]){1,2}$/
build2-refs-and-variables:
  script:
    - env | sort
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - production
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v[0-9](?:\.[0-9]){1,2}$/
```

I tried different cases on different branches with and without tags and checked which builds are triggered.

For tagged commit 2 pipelines are triggered. One with **CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=master** and missing **CI_COMMIT_TAG**, another with **CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME** and **CI_COMMIT_TAG** with the same tag value.

build2-refs-and-variables has never been triggered. Looks like condition for ref name and commit tag exclude each other. You should probably change your flow.

Comment: Is it really and? I thought the refs and varibale stuff is only to mix both, but is trigger also if only one of all is valid

Comment: For refs and variables gitlab-ci will join them with logical AND: (any of refs) AND (any of variables), so both must be TRUE to trigger job.

Comment: So are you saying there is no way I can have both master and tag at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you can always check my pipeline configuration on some test project and see what environment variables look like for tagged and non-tagged commits. Maybe you can find some pattern which satisfies your needs, but from my investigation your case won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. Your regex do not match to vx.x, I build a new one fitting this case [I build a new one fitting this case](https://regex101.com/r/FqPDOz/2)
2. In your if statement you try to match the tag with master or production, but I think tags are not fitting to a branch. So you have to validate tag or master or production

Comment: Thanks for your help. So how can I have the branch condition (master or production) and tag at the same time?

Comment: I think about it and change my answer, do you help this?

Comment: I don't think there is any CI_COMMIT_REF_BRANCH as per [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) 
If you meant CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME, this will have either a value of branch or tag, so when I have a tag for the commit it is a duplicate of $ CI_COMMIT_TAG.

Comment: Ok I have to think about and matey doing some test at weekend. But do you set version tags on the branches beside master and production?

Comment: Since master and production branches are protected, they only accept commit as an outcome of an MR. So when we need to have a release a release tag should be launched on the commit to any branch that would be merged to master. So the tag release may assign to any other branches as well.

Comment: A Tag is only assigned to one commit. So if you tag the commit before your merge, the tag will be the commit before merge and is not matched to the master branch, you should set the tag to the commit after merge

Comment: How can I do that? Are you saying I should tag the merge request itself? How?

Comment: no not the merge request, but there will be a commit after merge, this merge should be tagged, if this one is the new version. A tag is marking one commit, version tags are normally commits on the master branch. But normally mergerequest will be merged to develop and not directly to master and production. One best practice is to use gitflow https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/. Best practice is that the master branch represents the production system (or staging before production).

Comment: to tag a commit you can use git tag at any point, it should not blocked on protectet branched!?

Comment: It's about the permission. Only a maintainer can push something to a protected branch. But I guess we can delegate the release tag to a person with the maintainer role.